# Initialize type def field of a type def struct

Tags: c, field, typedef

```
MachineState machine;
ControlSignals theControls = machine.control_signals; //Why is this giving an error?

Error: traceTemp.c:4:38: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant. ControlSignals theControls = machine.control_signals;
```

Why is this giving an error? How do you access field of a type def which is also a typedef? Below is how I defined both of the typedefs. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
.
.
.
} ControlSignals;


typedef struct {
ControlSignals control_signals;
.
.
} MachineState;
```

Comment: Do you want `control_signals` to _be_ an instance of ControlSignals? i.e. putting that memory inside each MachineState variable.  Or do you want it to be a refer/pointer to a separate ControlSignals variable, i.e. the `machine` variable above?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a variable at file scope (i.e. outside of a function), the initializer must be a compile time constant as the error message states.  A compile time constant means (loosely speaking) a numeric constant, a string constant, or a grouping of those.  You are instead setting it to the value of another variable.

You need to either use constant values to initialize the variable or set it via assignment later in the program.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. How/why would I assign a string constant to a typedef with multiple int fields. Or, am I not supposed to do that? Can you please give me an example. I am new to using typedefs. Thanks!

Comment: @VrajShroff You didn't show what the struct contains.  That why I said numeric or string or a grouping of those.  If your struct contains only integer fields then you would supply integer values to initialize it, i.e. `ControlSignals theControls = { 1, 2, 6, 8, 2 ... };` with a value for each field.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that code is embedded in something unusual, the problem is not accessing the field. The problem is exactly what the error message says:  You're attempting to initialize the value of theControls, but the compiler doesn't know what the *compile time* value of machine.control_signals is, so it can't create the code to do that initialization.

To put it another way: In C, initialization of variables outside functions, like your example, requires a "constant expression": Something that the compiler can determine the value of, so that it can say what to pre-load into memory. You're getting the error message because you're not providing a *constant* expression.

Perhaps you're thinking of how automatic variables, those defined inside blocks, can be initialized at run time with an assignment.  But that's not what's happening here.

Comment: Why would not making *static* ControlSignals theControls... solve the problem?